# After upgrading Gulp, javascript is throwing an syntax-error "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a `gulpfile.js` that watch file changes in a folder. Everything was working fine until I upgraded from Gulp 3.9.1 to 4.0.2. When upgrading the Gulp, I also upgraded my node.js to the latest `v12.17.0`

Here is my gulp task that bundles the js files

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    filter = require('gulp-filter'),
    merge = require("merge-stream");

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    var tasks = [];

    var task = gulp.src(['path_1/**/*.js', 'path_2/**/*.js'], { base: "." })
            .pipe(filter('**/*.js'))
            .pipe(concat('output.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("."));

    tasks.push(task);

    return merge(tasks);
});
```

The task generates the following code

```
// More Js code...
import { setTimeout } from "timers";

'use strict';
// more js code.....
```

But the line `import { setTimeout } from "timers";` is throwing the following error

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at the level of a
>   module

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The above problem might be caused due to the attempt to import ***setTimeout*** as a module.

***setTimeout*** is a standard javascript function and it need not be imported explicitly. Therefore, removing the import statement may solve the issue.

If the above step does not fix the issue, then the following may be tried:

Add type="module" attribute to the **HTML script tag** that includes the module.

```
<script type="module" src="my-module.js"></script>
```

Comment: If gulp is generating the unnecessary import, then it could be a defect in that version of gulp. Can you please confirm if reverting to the older version of gulp fixes the issue?

Comment: I think gulp is what is generating the `import { setTimeout } from "timers";` code. I don't have that in my code. While adding `type="module"` did not work.

Comment: I tired Gulp `4.0.0` and `4.0.1` both gave me the same error `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: timers`

Comment: Thanks, John. The error can be considered as a defect in Gulp version 4.

Comment: I submitted a bug for gulp, but they said it has nothing to do with gulp. Not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: Hi John, If reverting to the older version of gulp (3.9.1) fixes the issue, then that can be the easy solution. The other solution is to try an alternative to gulp (webpack / custom nodejs script / grunt / yarn / pnpm / parcel, etc)